# App black screens after launch. iphone SDK 4.0

Tags: ios4

I've tried searching high and low for the answer to this weird problem.

My app worked perfectly with the last SDK, my app even worked with iOS4...

I upgraded to the newest iphone SDK 4, and now when I try to simulate my app it just black screens (Same thing happens when I try run it on my provisioned device).

It compiles fine with no errors, the console doesn't come up with any errors, the app just begins to launch briefly showing default.png and then it just black screens.

I've tried creating a new project and moving all my code over to it, doesn't help...

Anyone else have this problem? Anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, solved.

So embarrassing. Line missing:

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

=.=

Comment: Jeremy, consider accepting your answer so it's clear that it solved your problem.